# 'document' is undefined in Greasemonkey

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

Not more than ten minutes ago I decided to write my first script for Greasemonkey. I have zero experience with it. Also, my JavaScript is a bit rusty as it's been a while since I last wrote code in it. But I can't figure out why Greasemonkey is giving me this error:

```
Line: 9 
Char: 2 
Error: 'document' is undefined 
Code: 800A1391 
Source: Microsoft JScript runtime error
```

Here's my script:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           Easier WatchSeries
// @namespace      n/a
// @include        http://www.watch-series.com/episode/*
// ==/UserScript==

function thing()
{
    document.body.setAttribute('onload', show_links(document.getElementById('idepisod').value));
}
thing();
```

All I want to do is add an onLoad attribute to the body tag. I get this error when I go to "Manage New User Scripts" -> "Edit". Other than that the script does nothing so obviously something is wrong.

I'm running Firefox 3.6.13.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Several things:

1. [That cryptic error message has been found to happen when Greasemonkey does not have a proper editor set up](http://userscripts.org/topics/59474).

   1. Open **about:config** in your browser.
   2. Filter on **greasemonkey.editor**.
   3. Enter a valid path to a valid editor.  I like [TextPad](http://www.textpad.com/products/textpad/index.html), but `c:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe` should work on most windows systems.
   4. You *might* need to restart Firefox.
2. Event listeners cannot be added that way due to Greasemonkey's sandbox/security.  See [GM pitfalls, event handlers](http://commons.oreilly.com/wiki/index.php/Greasemonkey_Hacks/Getting_Started#Pitfall_.232%3a_Event_Handlers).
3. You need to [use `unsafeWindow` to call a page's JS functions](http://commons.oreilly.com/wiki/index.php/Greasemonkey_Hacks/Getting_Started#Pitfall_.238%3a_Calling_Remote_Page_Scripts), like `show_links()`.
4. When using complicated ajax functions that often fail, it's a good idea to wrap them in `try - catch` blocks.
5. That page switches between *www.watch-series.com* and *watch-series.com*, so both need to be in the `@include` directives.

Putting it all together, your script would become:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           Easier WatchSeries
// @namespace      n/a
// @include        http://www.watch-series.com/episode/*
// @include        http://watch-series.com/episode/*
// ==/UserScript==

function my_func()
{
    try
    {
        unsafeWindow.show_links(document.getElementById('idepisod').value);
    }
    catch (zError)
    {
        alert (zError); //-- Use console.log() in place of alert(), if running Firebug.

    }
}

window.addEventListener ("load", my_func, false);
```

Comment: Thank you for your very thorough answer. It explains a lot but ultimately I still get the same error. I'm just trying to do a simple work around where I don't have to click on the "Show More Links" link and instead the links get loaded automatically. show_links() is a function that's a part of their JS files and basically makes an AJAX request for the additional links. It takes one parameter, which is the 'idepisod' (episode id). I'll keep messing around with it. Who knows, maybe I've installed the script incorrectly or something.

Comment: @user391369: When I install that script, and go to: http://watch-series.com/episode/how_i_met_your_mother_s1_e1-7177.html, the script works perfectly and I see all links.   If there is no key information missing from the question, then your GM may have [this problem](http://userscripts.org/topics/59474), or your FF may be infected with that insidious, Microsoft .Net plugin (You can check that, [here](https://panopticlick.eff.org/) ).

Comment: Ah yes, you know your Greasemonkey. The problem was that the editor was set to the wrong path. Now it all works. Thanks!