# Iterate all the script tag in a HTML page to find match of a regular expression

Tags: javascript, html, tags

I am writing a Greasemonkey script to find all the matches in 'script' tags' 'src' attribute using regular expression, if one match is found, put the content of 'src' in an array.

For example:

```
<script src="/web/scripts/webjsone.js" type="text/javascript">
<script src="/web/scripts/webjstwo.js" type="text/javascript">
<script src="/web/scripts/webjsthree.js" type="text/javascript">
```

My regular expression is

```
'/webjs/i'.
```

My question is that I could I get them in an easy way?
I am trying some JavaScript like this:

```
var srcPath = null;
var regEx = /webjs/i;
if (regEx.test(event.target.src)){
   srcPath = event.target.src;
}
```

Which definitely won't work. But I think there should be a easy way like this to go through all the script tag.

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll("script[src*='webjs']")` not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you access the DOM? Then the `document.getElementsByTagName("script")` method should help you. Use it to find all the script tags and then apply your regex to filter them (if necessary).

Comment: I am writing a grease monkey script. I tried this, and when I use alert(document.getElementsByTagName("script").length); it returns 0, which I don't know why.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/4813174/232175 for some prerequisites when using Greasemonkey.

Comment: I don't think that's the issue I met.

Comment: that alert should never be 0. move your code out of greasemonkey and into an external script tag you control. then just inject the script with GM. easier to maintain, regular JS rules make it more intuitive, better analytics, bookmarklet-compat, yada yada.